# Destructor on const char *

Tags: c++, destructor

In my program, i have line like this:

```
    const char * str  = getStr();
```

Do i need to call destructor on str [] at the end of function to prevent memory leaks?

Comment: It depends if getStr allocates memory or not.

Comment: Since this is tagged `C++`, you should consider using a `std::string`.

Comment: Aside from everything that was said, you can't call a *destructor* on a `const char*` c-string. You could only, like said, `delete` or `free()` is. :) /nit-picking

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Question does not contain enough information to tell, it depends what `getStr()` does. For example:

```
const char *getStr() {
    return "boo";
}
```

then you *must not* call delete.

```
const char *getStr() {
    return new char;
}
```

then you should call `delete str;` to avoid a memory leak (and must not call `delete[]`).

```
const char *getStr() {
    return new char[10];
}
```

then you should call `delete[] str;` to avoid a memory leak (and must not call `delete`).

```
const char *getStr() {
    return 0;
}
```

then it doesn't matter what you do, calling any kind of `delete` on `str` has no effect.

Ownership of resources, and how to release any resources owned, are part of the interface to a function, and should be documented at the same time as you document what the return value actually is.

Comment: You forget to add the option for using strdup or other C API to add the extra twist.

Comment: @Martin: true. I also didn't cover the possibility that `getStr()` returns a pointer to data associated with some custom reference-counted shared entity, and that a matching `freeStr()` function must be called to decrement that reference count.

Comment: True; but the `most common` situation for returning a C-String pointer is from a C library that will use the C-string manipulation routines. And in IMO is much more likely scenario than any you postulate above (apart from the string literal).

Comment: @Martin: in which case the most common case of a `char*` returned from a C string-manipulation routine is probably like `strcpy` - a pointer into the data it's handling, so the resource is the same as you already had. To be honest I only think I need one example - the point is that the questioner *must* look it up, there is no point guessing regardless of what's common or uncommon.

Comment: Though the result is that the questioner must look it up, I think the point that we should be emphasizing is that pointer interfaces are inherently unclear and as such should not be used. Ultimately there are better design opportunities in C++ (that do not happen in C).

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what `getStr()` does. It may even be that you have to call `free` on the pointer if `getStr()` created it with `malloc`. It may be that `getStr()` is returning a pointer to a static area (not very thread safe, but it happens) or any number of other things.

Part of the contract and documentation for `getStr()` should be who owns the pointer it returns.

Here are some examples of possible `getStr()` functions...

In this case `getStr()` owns the pointer and you don't have to do anything to free it. OTOH, what's being pointed at may change the next time you call `getStr()` so you should probably make your own copy if you need to keep it around for any length of time:

```
const char *getStr()
{
    static char buf[30] = "Silly counter";

    buf[0] = buf[0] + 1;
    return buf;
}
```

In this case, you will eventually need to call `free` on the pointer returned:

```
const char *getStr()
{
    return strdup("Silly string");
}
```

In this case, you will need to call plain old `delete` on the pointer returned:

```
const char *getStr()
{
    return new char;
}
```

In this case, you will need to call `delete []` on the pointer returned:

```
const char *getStr()
{
    return new char[50];
}
```

There are many other possibilities. As I stated previously, part of the contract for a function (which should appear in its documentation) is who owns the pointer returned and how that data pointed to must be disposed of if doing so is the caller's responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how `getStr()` has been designed. It could return a pointer to a string that is still owned by someone else (and in this case the answer is no) or it may return a pointer to and the caller becomes the owner (and in this case the answer is yes).

You should check the documentation of `getStr` to know.

If the ownership of the returned area is of the caller then probably in C++ returning an `std::string` would have been a much better idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to do so if it's going out of scope. I'd recommend also setting the pointer to null to ensure it isn't dangling:

```
delete[] str;
str = null;
```

Comment: I noticed and fixed it just a moment ago :)

Comment: setting pointers to NULL is a sign of other problems in your code and with RAII it becomes unnecessary. As a result I would advise against it in C++ code as it actually hides errors during development. Of course if this was a C question then your point would be valid (but it still hides problems).